# how to convert 12 hrs format to 24 hrs format in kettle

Tags: kettle, geokettle

I have CSV file that contains timestamp column and data type is a string. It looks like this.

```
timestamp 
12/03/2016 01:00 PM
12/04/2016 01:15 PM
12/04/2016 01:30 PM
```

So I want to convert time value in 24 hrs format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

PDI Kettle is a Java application. Use java formatting rules 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

[image]